# Cosmological constant, dynamical friction and structure formation?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy, cosmological-constant, structure-formation

I would like to ask a question about an interesting article that I found (https://repositorio.unesp.br/server/api/core/bitstreams/b8a5a5b8-4b3b-4198-9f5d-bf69431db1ae/content)

In the context of structure formation, I can see there there is a positive contribtuion from Λ (the cosmological constant) that goes against the gravitational attraction and dynamical friction. I was told by one of the authors that as Λ gravitates repulsively, it is able to balance the gravity of the mass distribution at a certain radius. Even if the overdensity is big, if you go far enough you will find particles with escape energy thanks to Λ. Also, they said that dynamical friction is a phenomenon that occurs within a density distribution, so it contributes wherever there is density. As seen in the paper, it tends to go in the same direction as gravity, and dissipate energy.

My question is, would particles that are escaping (with a bit of help from the "escape energy" contributed by Lambda) suffer dynamical friction from the other elements in the overdensity that would dissipate part of their initial energy and the bit of "escape energy" added by Lambda? Would this dynamical friction cause some form of heat (for example through tidal interactions between rearranged objects)?

Or is this reasoning wrong in some way (If the question is downvoted I will assume it is wrong, but I would like to be corrected in that case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamical friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_friction) is a process where the kinetic energy of a heavy particle gets converted into the kinetic and gravitational energy of other, smaller particles in a gravitationally bound system. Roughly, the gravitational pull of particles in the wake of the moving particle cause it to slow down, and by Newton's third law the pull of the moving particle on the other particles in the system cause them to speed up. You can think of this process as kinetic energy of the original particle getting dissipated as heat into the gravitationally bound system, hence the word "friction."

So I would tend to agree with what you've written in this paragraph:

> My question is, would particles that are escaping (with a bit of help from the "escape energy" contributed by Lambda) suffer dynamical friction from the other elements in the overdensity that would dissipate part of their initial energy and the bit of "escape energy" added by Lambda? Would this dynamical friction cause some form of heat (for example through tidal interactions between rearranged objects)?

The one comment I would make (and this is probably implicitly understood by the authors) is that a cosmological constant does not *literally* create an "anti-gravitational" force that pulls particles out of overdensities. Rather, it causes the expansion of the Universe as a whole to accelerate. If the Universe was perfectly smooth, then it would cause different "patches" of the Universe to expand away from each other at an exponentially increasing rate. When you add overdensities into the picture, this becomes complicated because the gravitational attraction of the overdensity holds itself together. However, especially for large structures like galaxy clusters that are weakly bound, the effect of the expansion can lead to an "effective force" that tends to "flatten" the overdensity or even pull particles out of it. See, eg, the Appendix of https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0609100.

Comment: thank you. And would dynamical friction cause tidal interactions and forces between the affected objects (perhaps by arranging then in certain configurations)? @Andrew

Comment: @vengaq Dynamical friction isn't a tidal effect per se, in the sense that (as I normally understand it), it corresponds to a net force on a moving object that we can consider point like -- you can have dynamical friction without noticeable tides that are deforming the moving object. There is a sense in which tides are present... since there is more mass in the wake of the moving object than ahead of it, there is a non-uniform gravitational field. However, typically these non-uniformities occur on a scale larger than the size of the affected object.

Comment: a while ago a physicist told me that dynamical friction could re-arrange objects in different configurations and this indirectly could cause tidal forces, I was thinking about tides more in that sense. Nevertheless, then the object would feel some tidal force due to the non-uniformity of gravitational forces that you described? @Andrew

Comment: @vengaq At a words level I could see how that would make sense, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about the details to add anything intelligent.